# Building Erlang Client for Couch Base Server 1.8 and 2.0

Tags: database, erlang, couchdb, couchbase

We have used [Couchbase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/) in our product. Its an Intranet application whose front end is pure JavaScript. We however use [Erlang/OTP](http://erlang.org) for the Business Logic, authentication (`Mnesia`), [yaws web server](http://yaws.hyber.org) and a bunch of other erlang libraries.
Now, we are still using the `Couch Base Single Server` whose download has been removed from the [Couch base site](http://www.couchbase.com). We have found it very stable. In now, 5 months of running live, it has never gone down. We are running it on top of Ubuntu Server. So, our interest in NoSQL is just beginning. 
However, as i asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10750986/431620) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9462995/431620) here about `Erlang Client` support for Couch base server, i discovered that they say:

```
Couchbase Server is memcached compatible. This means many existing memcached 
client libraries and in many cases, the applications already using these 
libraries, may be used directly with Couchbase Server
```

So i then started looking around for these ***memcached compatible*** libraries and have found a bunch of them: at [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients#Erlang), [Erlang Mc](http://code.google.com/p/erlangmc/),[erlmc](http://jkvor.com/erlang-binary-protocol-memcached-client), [mcache](https://github.com/echou/memcached-client/), [memcached-client](https://github.com/higepon/memcached-client) and finally [OneCached By Process One (Makers of Ejjabberd XMPP Server)](https://git.process-one.net/onecached). With my great aim (if possible), of implementing my own client for Couch Base server 1.8 and 2.0 , the question follows:

**1 . Which of the above memcached Erlang Client libraries is appropriate for use with Couchbase 1.8 and 2.0 ?**
**2. If it is compatible, can i directly use it, or i have to make some changes first ?  please do explain the changes ?** 
**3.  Is anyone out there feeling the need for Erlang Client support for Couch Base server 2.0 and 1.8 as we do ? How are they working their way around this problem ?** 
I would appreciate it, if a Couch Base `insider` having membership here on stackoverflow, do tell us if Couch base team has plans of building us an Erlang Client possibly in any near future so that we do not waste our time attempting so, as they are in position of building a much better and efficient client to their own server, than we can. 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase doesn't have any plans to release an erlang client in the near term. We use Erlang in our product and really like Erlang, but don't have time to put together an Erlang client at the moment. If you are interested in developing an Erlang client we are certainly happy to help and will answer any questions you might have. If you send me an email (see my profile) I will help get you in contact with someone at Couchbase who can help answer questions and get you started on development.

Also, I am not an Erlang user so I am unable to answer any of your questions related to memcached Erlang libraries. Hopefully someone who has can help you.

Comment: your email is hidden in the Profile.

Comment: I think I tracked down your gmail address and just sent you an email. If that doesn't get to you I will post my email address here.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried erlmc.  I make heavy use of it for storing 32K binaries and it has worked great so far.