# Erlang views with couchbase

Tags: erlang, view, couchdb, couchbase

Is anybody using Erlang views with Couchbase? If so what do you do it and what are your experiences?

I'm thinking of migrating from CouchDB to Couchbase...

Thanks
  Thanos

Comment: Is there an offical Erlang client for couchbase?

Comment: look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9462995/431620  , http://stackoverflow.com/q/11204896/431620 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/10750986/431620

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Server 2.0 only supports JavaScript views. However, we've made major changes to the way we execute the JavaScript, so there is no longer a performance reason to write your views in Erlang.

Details: We moved from Spidermonkey to V8, and we are have an in-process model now, so that we don't have to send data between processes.

Here are the details on Couchbase views for 2.0: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views.html